# For loop in Function node only returning the first iteration

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am trying to create a loop in a function node in Node-Red that basically acts like a countdown timer for me. Right now when I run this node I only get a single output from the node with msg.playload saying "Back in 15 minutes".

What I want is to get 15 outputs one after another that say "Back in 15 minutes", "Back in 14 minutes", ect. Once I can get that I will add in a delay so that the for loop waits for 1 minute each time it runs.

```
var totalMinutes = 15

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    var minutesLeft = totalMinutes - [i];

    msg.payload = {
        "profile": {
            "status_text": "Back in " + minutesLeft + " minutes",
            "status_emoji": ":coffee:",
            "status_expiration": 0
        }
    };
    return [msg.payload];
}

return [msg];
```

Comment: You also need to return a whole `msg` object, not just `msg.payload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are stopping the code from continuing by using `return [msg.payload];`. Remove that line and it should print out the way you want it.

Note that the print out is not equivalent to 1 second. To do that you can wrap in a `setInterval()`

checkout https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp for more details.

Comment: When I do this I only get the results from the last iteration. It shows that I'll be back in 1 minute, but skips 15-2. I want the function node to output 15 different times.

Comment: Figured this out. I had to delete the return, but then I also added `node.send(msg);` to the end of my for loop and now I'm getting exactly what I wanted.